# Expected something between the word 'Alias Name' and the 'ON' keyword

Tags: teradata, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to run this query and getting the below error.
Can you please let me know why this might be failing?

```
Error:Syntax error: expected something between the word 'FWI14' and the 'ON' keyword.
SELECT Command Failed.
```

Query:

```
SELECT FISCAL_MONTH, FISCAL_YEAR, 
CASE WHEN END_dATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'C' ELSE 'X' END CURR_INDICATOR, 
BEGIN_DATE,
END_DATE
FROM corp.fiscal_month_info FMI12
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT END_dATE FROM corp.fiscal_week_info  
WHERE CURRENT_dATE BETWEEN BEGIN_dATE AND END_dATE) AS FWI14 
ON FWI14.FISCAL_MONTH = FMI12.FISCAL_MONTH
AND FWI14.FISCAL_YEAR = FMI12.FISCAL_YEAR
```

Comment: It looks OK to me.  I don't think this is it, but the only thing I can think of is to include the join columns in the `SELECT` of your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - `SELECT END_DATE, FISCAL_MONTH, FISCAL_YEAR FROM corp.fiscal_week_info`...but I'm pretty sure that's not necessary.

Comment: How are you submitting the query - BTEQ, SQLA?

Comment: As written, corp.fiscal_week_info may have those columns, but FWI14 does not. They definitely need to be included in the SELECT list in the subquery before you can reference them in the outer query.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Pls remove below bold command(**AS**). This is not a column you are aliasing but a subquery.

```
SELECT FISCAL_MONTH, FISCAL_YEAR, 
CASE WHEN END_dATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'C' ELSE 'X' END CURR_INDICATOR, 
BEGIN_DATE,
END_DATE
FROM corp.fiscal_month_info FMI12
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT END_dATE FROM corp.fiscal_week_info    
WHERE CURRENT_dATE BETWEEN BEGIN_dATE AND END_dATE) **AS** FWI14 
ON FWI14.FISCAL_MONTH = FMI12.FISCAL_MONTH  
AND FWI14.FISCAL_YEAR = FMI12.FISCAL_YEAR
```

Comment: Every DBMS (besides Oracle) supports Standard SQL aliases using the optional `AS` keyword